# Git error while cloning a repository with submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I just started learning about git submodules and while I was experimenting with it I ran into an error I can't solve. The details are the following:

In a directory on my machine called `Sandbox` I've created the following folders: `local-repo1`, `local-repo2,` remote-repo`. My goal was to create a remote repository based on` local-repo1`inside`remote-repo`and then pull from that remote to`local-repo2`, practically to make a working copy of` local-repo1`.

Here is the directory structure of `local-repo1`:

```
local-repo1
├── .git
├── .gitmodules
├── project1
│   └── data
└── project2
    ├── .git
    └── data
```

The content of `.gitmodules`:

```
[submodule "project2"]
    path = project2
    url = ./project2
    branch = master
```

I made one commit on `project2` then I added it to the parent repository with the `git submodule add` command, later made a commit on that repository too. The next step was pushing to `remote-repo`, where I already created a bare repository. Everything went well.

Finally I initalized a repository in `local-repo2` and pulled the content from `remote-repo`.
Things went well, but when I looked inside `project2`, it was empty and when I attempted to resolve it with `git submodule update --init` I got the following error:

```
Submodule 'project2' (../remote-repo/project2) registered for path 'project2'
fatal: repository '../remote-repo/project2' does not exist
fatal: clone of '../remote-repo/project2' into submodule path '/home/user/Sandbox/local-repo2/project2' failed
Failed to clone 'project2'.
```

Assume that data inside `project2` is crucial to `local-repo2` to compile and work. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Looks like upstream registered `../remote-repo/project2` as a subproject which of course makes no sense outside of their environment. Can you examine the `git submodule` configuration?

Comment: I edited the question, now it contains the configuration file as well.

Comment: The observation remains; `./project` is not a valid URL outside of the context where it was created. You need to use a portable URL when you `git submodule add` it (perhaps it should even be reported as a bug that Git allowed this URL). It should look like `url = https://github.com/you/project2.git` or similar

Comment: Perhaps let's circle back to what you actually want to accomplish here, though. If `project2` is a subdirectory of `local-repo1` and you don't use it for anything else then just don't make it a submodule at all. Submodules make sense when you have a component which makes sense as a subcomponent of multiple unrelated projects, and perhaps even in isolation.

Comment: Originally I developed a utility module for a monolithic application and now I want to embed it without losing it's history. I thought git submodules could be a solution for that scenario. This sample project is a preliminary test how would it worked with my actual situation.

Comment: Then it should work, but you need to push it to a central location and clone it from there. It doesn't have to be Github, of course; but the URL needs to be one which Git can use to connect to the repo you want to clone the submodule _from._ If it's not yet in a separate repo, that will need to be your first step. The command `git submodule add` means basically "create a slave of a remote within this repo"; but the master needs to exist somewhere else.

Comment: Good to hear, thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, the problem is that you cannot *create* a new project in this way. `git submodule add` wants as its argument the URL of an existing Git repository whose project you would like to add as a submodule here. The URL needs to resolve in the same way as `git clone` requires as its argument a remote repository which it can connect to and fetch.